# Gnuplot script to output eps or svg - how to write?

Tags: svg, gnuplot, eps

I have the following gnuplot script:

```
set autoscale
unset log
unset label
set xtic auto
set ytic auto
unset title
set xlabel "Number of clusters"
set ylabel "Accuracy of classifier (%)"
plot "cluster.dat" using 1:3 title "PART" with lines, \
     "cluster.dat" using 1:4 title "JRip" with lines, \
     "cluster.dat" using 1:5 title "FURIA" with lines
```

I would like this script, when run, to output SVG or EPS - what would I need to add or modify to make this happen?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `gnuplot` the output type is called `terminal`.

In your script, before the `plot` command use

```
set term svg
set output "output.svg"
```

or

```
set term eps
set output "output.eps"
```

both terminals have several options. Type `help eps` (on some gnuplot this is `help epscairo`) or `help svg`.

To get the list of available terminals for your build, type `set terminal`.